# PHP Static class variables, inheritance, and garbage collection

Tags: php, memory, inheritance, static

I am having some memory problems with a script that uses objects set up with inherited static variables like this.

```
class a
{
    public static $a = "a";
}

class b extends a
{
    private $instanceVar = 'hey';
    private $otherVar = 'you';

    public function DoStuff()
    {
        echo self::$a;
    }
}
```

then code that uses the classes like this

```
while(condition)
{
    $obj = new b();
    $obj -> DoStuff();
    unset($obj);
}
```

My question is, will unsetting obj trigger garbage collection and the unsetting of its instance variables since it also holds a reference to the the inherited static variable?

Answer (score 2):

`unset` in this code doesn't bring anything.

With and without it the object will be successfully collected when it's possible.

> will unsetting obj trigger garbage collection

Not it won't. Garbage collector will be called automatically when it makes sense.

> since it also holds a reference to the the inherited static variable

It doesn't. Objects don't hold references to a static properties.

Answer (score -1):

If you care so much about GC and have PHP >= 5.3.0 have a look to 
[gc_collect_cycles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) and [garbage collection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) in general